# positioning elements in xamarin forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, icons

the info icon needs to be to the right of this label using c# only.
[image]

exa:

```
this.Content = new StackLayout
            {

                Children =
                {
                    infoIcon,
                    Label,
                    webView
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = 
            {
                Label,
                infoIcon,
            }
        },
        webView
    }
}
```

That's it, hope it helps!